# C# Printing a Certain Amount of Characters from a File

Tags: c#, file

So I'm trying to print out a certain amount of characters in a file. I already have code set up to where it prints out each line tha contains certain symbol or start with certain characters, but I want to print out a certain amount of characters.

I have this so far. I am trying other solutions, but they're not working as well as I thought.

```
if (info.Contains("-") || info.Contains("Con"))
{
   System.Console.WriteLine(info)
   count++; 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "a certain amount of characters"? The first N characters in each line? You should at least give some example: even the code snippet is just a very small section that does not explain what you would like to do.

Comment: By the way, if you're already splitting the file into lines this question has nothing to do with files: it's just about strings.

Answer (score 0):

Just use substring

```
System.Console.WriteLine(info.Substring(0, numberOfChars))
```

If you want to print to a File instead Console (as your example code does)

```
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"C:\File\file.txt"))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(info.Substring(0, numberOfChars));
        }
```